# simple RegEx expression assistance

Tags: regex

I am currently having issue to find the regex expression for my case:

The word "Test" as is, or with hashtag symbol and 1 digit between 2-9
For example:

A. Test (valid)
B. Test#3(valid)
C. Test# (invalid)
D. Test#1(invalid because it should be 2-9)
E. Test#10(invalid up to digit 9)
What i've tried: `\Test(#[2-9])?\`, the issue with this expression is that it will accept cases C & E.
Thanks in advance for any given help.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/cKrHUC/1

Comment: think about the start and end of the string anchors

Comment: Thank you all, totally missed that point of whole string (start to end) expression.